# Apache Error on Magento import

Tags: apache, magento

I'm trying to run an import script profile on Magento for importing around 1000+ products and I got this error:

```
mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 31 seconds
End of script output before headers: index.php
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: are you using import profile or custom script ?

Comment: Check this out: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/7467/mod-fcgid-read-data-timeout-in-45-seconds-premature-end-of-script-headers

Comment: @SimBeez i am using a profile. I fixed the issue. It turned out to be a timeout limitation in apache.